# should one return stop the whole program?

Tags: java

This is the leetcode question 9

```
    class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
       if(x<0 || (x!= 0 && x%10 == 0) ){
           return false;
       }
        int res = 0;
        while(x>res){
            res = res*10 + x % 10;
            if(x == res || x == res/10){
                return true;
            }
            x = x/10;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the correct answer, but I have a question.

```
if(x == res || x == res/10){
            return true;
        }
```

In this part, if return true, there will be a lot of true comes out after while loop completes. However, should one return stop the whole program?

Comment: return will in fact stop the loop

Comment: But in leetocode, this does not stop the loop

Comment: Sorry, but using a conjuntive makes your question ambiguous. If you want to know if the first return will stop the entire loop, the answer is YES. If you want to know if this is best practice, the answer is IT DEPENDS. There are cases when you indeed want to know the number of matches. Then you waint and count until the loop is over.

Comment: "Should one return stop the whole program": no.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually trying to find the mid point of the string and see if the 2 digits match.

Example:
Suppose the number is 5225. The iteration will look something like this:

res  x

1. 5    5225
2. 52   522
   Here res==x/10 -> returns true.

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question

Comment: The author is assuming, we'll have multiple true return statements in the above algorithm, however, that does not hold true, since the user is actually comparing the 2 halves of the integer. I've added the above comment to explain how the algo would exactly perform the iteration, thereby clearing his doubt.